# Coinbase Multiple Wallets

Tags: coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I'm getting this error while creating new accounts.

> (1/2) ClientException
>   Client error: `POST https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
>   {"errors":[{"id":"invalid_request","message":"Creation of multiple BTC accounts is not supported"}]}
>
> (2/2) InvalidRequestException Creation of multiple BTC accounts is not supported

Is this new? I have created multiple BTC accounts in the past but it does not work anymore. Is there any fix for this.

BTW I'm referring to https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#create-account

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did get a response from Coinbase saying they no longer support multiple wallets without giving a reason.

I guess time to find a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

According to this doc (which I believe is still valid but might not be), you can create multiple wallets: https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/guides/bitcoin-wallet

But, you must supply the correct permission key: https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#scopes

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience that this no longer works as well, but have been unable to find any mention of it being disabled. I can not create accounts other than vault accounts for any given currency on the Coinbase site either, so until Coinbase says otherwise, I am considering that the published API is out of sync with the actual implementation.